# Classpath specific to module in IntelliJ Gradle project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, classpath, build.gradle

I have an IntelliJ Gradle project which contains an Android module, a GWT module and a pure Java module.

Is there a way to add the classpath for `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'` such that it is not in a buildscript?

Here is my 'build.gradle' for the Android module:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    // workaround for "duplicate files during packaging of APK" issue
    // see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/bl5Rc4Szpzg/wC8cylTWuIEJ
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1+'
}
```

And here is my top-level 'build.gradle'

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: Because only one of my modules is based on Android, the AndroidGradle facet is applied to all the other modules, which I suspect interferes with GWT compiling.

Comment: You have to add this in the buildscript, but using it only in the android module, it shouldn't be a problem. What is your issue?

Comment: My buildscript that adds the Android facet is only included in the Android build.gradle. However, they are somehow still applied on my GWT and Java modules. It slows down my Gradle refresh, as well as adding an unnecessary facet to other modules. I just think that there should be a way to solve it.